# How to connect Eclipse JBPM projectr with external Database Oracle

Tags: database, oracle, eclipse, jbpm

JBPM Version 7.43
Oracle database connection

I am trying to connect to my local oracle database with JBPM Eclipse Project But it Takes internal H2 In memory Database

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by

> JBPM Eclipse Project

If you're just using your JBPM embeded in a Spring Boot app, then you just need to point out to your oracle db instance by changing some properties defined in your application.properties file. Have a look at https://docs.jbpm.org/7.73.0.Final/jbpm-docs/html_single/#_configuring_different_databases

In case you're using EAP for your jbpm projects, you need to setup your EAP to do so. In that case, have a look at https://docs.jbpm.org/7.73.0.Final/jbpm-docs/html_single/#_using_your_own_database_with_the_jbpm_installer